# How can I fix "System does not contain a definition for 'Text" error

Tags: c#

Revisiting some code that I haven't touched in a few weeks and now when I go to build it I get a few errors, one of them being:
 Code CS0117 'myNamespace.System' does not contain a definition for 'Text'
when trying the line:

```
string aFieldTitle = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace((string)af.title, "[^A-Za-z0-9_]", "").ToUpper();
```

I've already searched for reference(s) to add, but I don't see one for System.Text in the Reference Manager.

Comment: Where is myNamespace coming from?

Comment: `myNamespace.System` is **very** suspect.  Have you created your *own* `System` namespace in your code?  You should probably re-name it to something less conflicting.  Ambiguity in code is never a good thing.

Comment: remove the "using myNamespace = System;" line from the top of your file. You have some using alias that needs to be removed

Comment: So my code is wrapped in a namespace named myNamespace & at the top of my file I have 'using using System';& 'using System.Text;' 

I haven't written my own System class/namespace and when i hover over System it says myNamespace.System, but there is a red line under 'Text' and the error says 'System does not contain a definition for 'Text' '

Comment: Try replacing  `using System.Text;` with  `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` and remove the qualification `System.Text.RegularExpressions`  from the regex declaration! Also: Why do you need to cast  an item to string which already is called `title`?

Comment: So @TaW's suggestions works; I wish I knew why because thats weird - its practically the same thing. 

Also, its legacy code so I don't know why they decided to do that but 'title' is of type dynamic